# Understanding promises in javascript using when library

Tags: javascript, node.js, when-js

I've been trying to wrap my head around asynchronous programming and the use of promises. To help understand them, I've written some trivial nested code, but have run into a snag.

Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/hBtk9vER
Make sure you install when library (npm install)

```
var when = require('when');

function promise() {
  console.log("Promise");
    promiseRead().then(function(string) {
    console.log("Inner promise");
    console.log(string);
    });
}

function promiseRead() {
  console.log("PromiseRead");
  return baz().then(function() {
    console.log("Inner Read");
    var deferred = when.defer();
    setTimeout(function() {
      deferred.resolve("Hello World");
    }, 5000);
  });
}

function baz() {
  console.log("BAZ");
  return when(true); 
}

promise();
```

My problem is that `console.log(string)` is undefined, when I was expecting it to be `"Hello World"` after `promiseRead()` resolves. Interestingly, when I remove the timeout, it works as expected. Can anybody help explain this, why the `promise` function is executing it's code before `promiseRead()` has finished timeout.

Much appreciated

Comment: I do not have time for a full answer, but in your `Inner Read` you don't return anything (no promise) so your `var deferred = when.defer();` at this place is useless.

Comment: To add to that, I know you're experimenting, but promises are not much help if you don't use them in a structured way. The point of promises (IMO) is to organize async code linearly. You could make this even more convoluted by adding rejections and passing deferreds around, but I hope you can see now why it's important to keep promise-based code clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to return your deferred object in promiseRead()

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I was under the impression that `deferred.resolve()` would return a deferred object, but than obviously didn't think about the asynchronous nature of the language. So in my example, was `promiseRead` returning null, before the deferred resolved and the function above it on the stack, had no way of knowing that a promise had to be waiting?

Answer (score 1):

some updates

```
var when = require('when');

function promise() {
  console.log("Promise");
    promiseRead().then(function(string) {
    console.log("Inner promise");
    console.log(string);
    });
}

function promiseRead() {
  console.log("PromiseRead");
  return baz().then(function() {
    console.log("Inner Read");
    var deferred = when.defer();
    setTimeout(function() {
      deferred.resolve("Hello World");
    }, 5000);
    return deferred.promise;
  });
}

function baz() {
  console.log("BAZ");
  return when(true); 
}

promise();
```

Comment: Is this an answer to your question? Is there still a problem within it?  If it is an answer to your question then take the time to explain how you solved it.